# Can't increase media file size limit in Wordpress, tried everything

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to increase my upload file size limit in my Wordpress site - it's currently set at just 2MB. I have tried everything, from editing functions.php, creating a php.ini file, updating the .htaccess file, calling my hosting provider who told me "you're on the right track!" and offered no other help. When I look at the info for the site [(here!)](http://beta.redpariseyewear.com/wp-content/themes/monochrome-pro/info.php) it says my upload limit is 64M, which is what I set it to following all the tutorials I read, but when I actually look in my media uploader in Wordpress, it still has a limit of 2MB. Am I missing something? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After tearing my hair out, I figured out the solution: the php.ini file needs to go in the wp-admin folder. All the tutorials I read specified other folders to put this file in (everything from the theme folder to the cgi-bin folder, etc). In the end, it worked fine in the wp-admin folder, I can now see my limit in the uploader is at 64m. If anyone else is struggling, try that!

Answer (score 0):

I see you found the solution already though a good practice is to increase 2 variables in the php.ini file, located to the folder of your site:
post_max_size 200M 
upload_max_filesize 200M

That will set-up the limit to 200Mb and after clearing cache you should see it in the Media tab in the WordPress Dahsboard.

Unless if there is another limit involved from the hosting, that should work like a charm.